# Ajax no responde o no reconoce una URL que le doy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Es la primera vez que trabajo con Ajax, lo que quiero lograr en mi sistema es que cuando el primer campo pierda el foco el resto de campos se autocompleten automáticamente con los datos que están en la base de datos.

Antes de llamar al Ajax, probé mostrar una alerta para ver si el script está funcionando correctamente, y efectivamente lo hizo.

El problema es que luego de crear un archivo aparte donde van las sentencias SQL que envían los datos a la función que está en el script, y poner otro alert para saber si sigue funcionando, no me muestra nada cuando el primer campo pierde el foco.

La verdad pienso que puede ser que no esté el reconociendo el archivo que lleva las sentencias, pero como no tengo experiencia con Ajax no estoy segura.

Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda, a continuación dejo los códigos:

La parte donde están los inputs, cabe aclarar que aún he puesto los echos para que muestren los datos

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
    <div class="id">ID Proveedor</div><input type="text" name="id" class="id-form" id="id" onblur="buscarProveedor();"> 
    <div class="pro">Nombre</div><input type="text" name="proveedor" class="pro-form" id="proveedor">
    <div class="dir">Dirección</div><input type="text" name="direccion" class="dir-form" id="direccion">
    <div class="con">Contacto</div><input type="text" name="contacto" class="con-form" id="contacto">
    <div class="tel">Teléfono</div><input type="text" name="telefono" class="tel-form" id="telefono">
    <div class="clas">Clase de producto</div><input type="text" name="clase" class="clas-form" id="clase">
</form>
```

El script:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">

function buscarProveedor() {

    id = $("#id").val();

    var parametros = 
    {
        "buscar": 1,
        "id": id

    };
    $.ajax(
    {
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'papeleria/controllers/buscar.prov.controller.php',
        type: 'post',

        beforeSend: function(){
            alert("enviando");},
        error: function(){
            alert("error"); },
        complete: function(){
            alert("listo"); },
        success: function(valores){

            alert(valores.nombre)

        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Esto es lo que hay en el archivo de las secuencias, la ruta en la que está es `controllers/buscar.prov.controllers.php`, la del archivo donde está el formulario y el script es `views/inventario/proveedores.view.php`

```php
<?php

include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $valores = array();
    $valores['existe'] = "0";

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM proveedores_ WHERE id_proveedor_ = $id");

    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        $valores['existe'] = "1";
        $valores['nombre_'] = $resultado['nombre_'];
        $valores['direccion'] = $resultado['direccion_'];
        $valores['contacto_del_proveedor_'] = $resultado['contacto_del_proveedor_'];
        $valores['telefono_'] = $resultado['telefono_'];
        $valores['clase_id_'] = $resultado['nombre_'];
        $valores['cuenta_asociada_'] = $resultado['cuenta_asociada_'];
    }
    $valores = json_encode($valores);
    echo $valores;
}

?>
```

En el error.log de Apache me muestra estos errores

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:45.751861 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:46.046399 2022] [core:warn] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:46.089332 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:47.151666 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH00455: Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:47.151666 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Dec 17 2021 10:17:38

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:47.151666 2022] [core:notice] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:47.275472 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11368:tid 592] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7032

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:50.785581 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 7032:tid 588] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:51.158698 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 7032:tid 588] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

> [Wed Jun 08 21:36:51.502158 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7032:tid 588] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Además de no rellenar el resto de campos... ¿Da algún error la llamada a Ajax? ¿Se ejecuta algún `alert` o sale algún mensaje de error en el navegador o inspector? Otro tema a estudiar es si es mejor utilizar POST o GET, o por ejemplo utilizar una variable tipo `accion` con valores diferentes en lugar de `buscar:1` que aunque funciona, se hace raro.

Comment: Ha revisado el error.log de Apache?

Comment: @VFG No, no muestra absolutamente nada,. ¿El accion cómo lo usaría para reemplazar el buscar:1, o sea, qué valor le daría?

Comment: @Duston en la publicación te dejé la serie de errores que me muestra el error.log

Comment: En el campo data, mándalo como JSON, así: `data: { "buscar": "1", "id": id}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por responder. Inspeccioné de nuevo la página y me decía que había una variable indefinida. Al parecer estaba cargando sin la librería de jQuery, así que añadí el link del código de jQuery antes del script, y ahora si funciona.

Justo en esta línea

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
```

PD: Me respondí yo misma para poder cerrar la pregunta